# Epson Stylus SX420W doesn't print due to "Printer needs epson-espcr-wrapper package before printing." error

Tags: installation, drivers, epson

I'm trying to install Epson Stylus SX420W. I have PPD file, I connect printer with USB and install it with PPD. It recognizes printer and install it but it gives this message `Printer needs epson-espcr-wrapper package before printing. Install it.`.

What is `epson-espcr-wrapper` package? How can I install it?

Comment: espcr should be escpr (ESC/P-R is the new standard language for Epson inkjet printers).
http://global.epson.com/innovation/universal_printing/driver_library.html

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-cache search escpr
```

gives:

```
epson-escpr - transitional dummy package for epson-escpr printer driver
libescpr-dev - printer driver for Epson Inkjet - library development files
libescpr1 - printer driver for Epson Inkjet - shared library
printer-driver-escpr - printer driver for Epson Inkjet that use ESC/P-R
```

I suggest to install `printer-driver-escpr`.
`epson-escpr-wrapper` is a cups filter and is likely to be found in `/usr/lib/cups/filter/`.

If that does not work out, [download and install the deb package from openprinting.org](http://www.openprinting.org/driver/epson-escpr/).

```
sudo dpkg -i epson-inkjet-printer-escpr_{version}{arch}.deb
```

Comment: `printer-driver-escpr` did it for me. Works well over WiFi with old Epson Stylus SX420W

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the requested package using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install epson-inkjet-printer-escpr
```